# How can I install unity instead of gnome in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: desktop-environments

I want to install unity as DE in Ubuntu 18.04.Is it possible.

Comment: `sudo apt install unity` and then restart and select `Unity` as DE from login page

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

Run:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

Then logout. Select Unity as the desktop environment and then login as normal.

Once you're logged in with Unity, you may remove GNOME if you want. Do so with the following commands:

```
sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt remove gdm3
sudo apt autoremove
```

Then install LightDM:

```
sudo apt install lightdm
```

If prompted to choose default Window Manager during installation, select LightDM.

Reboot and you should boot into the LightDM login screen. You can then login and you should be greeted by the Unity desktop.